# Angular 6 - Comparação de valores

Tags: javascript, angular

No banco de dados eu salvo um numero inteiro para representar o tipo de usuário. O número inteiro pode receber 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ou 7.

Quando vou mostrar o tipo de usuário na tela, eu teria que fazer vários *ngIf para mostrar o valor no componente html.

```
<td *ngIf="user.profile == 1"> Administrador </td>
<td *ngIf="user.profile == 2"> Avaliador </td>
<td *ngIf="user.profile == 3"> Responsável </td>

E outros 4 *ngIf para validar o restante...
```

Para não precisar fazer esses *ngIf, teria uma outra maneira melhor? Não queria colocar 7 validações só para mostrar um resultado no componente html.

Comment: O certo era sua api retronar um campo contendo este numero e um campo com o nome do campo. Ai voce so utilizaria assim: {{user.campo}}

Comment: Vc tbm pode usar enums no seu typescript mas  seria uma solução hard-coded que se algo mudar no backend vc tem que mudar no front tbm.

Comment: @EduardoVargas como seria a validação para comparar com enum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você vai exibir apenas um de cada vez, talvez faça mais sentido fazer o "calculo" do que será exibido no código e mostrar com uma função:

TS:

```
function nomePerfil(perfil: number) : string {
  switch (perfil) {
    case 1: return "Administrador ";        
    case 2: return "Avaliador";    
    ...     
    default: return "";
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<td>{{nomePerfil(user.profile)}}</td>
```

**EDITADO**

Usando o `Enum` , sugerido pelo @EduardoVargas, fica bem mais simples a função, bastando você declarar o `Enum`:

TS

```
export enum Perfil {
  Administrador,
  Avaliador,
  Responsável,
}
```

HTML

```
<td>{{Perfil[user.profile]}}</td>
```

Acredito que chamando o `Enum` como acima funciona, se não funcionar você pode colocar esse código dentro da função `nomePerfil` sugerida anteriormente.